# Help center headings are too subtle

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, user-interface, help-center

The help center headings have changed to something I find too subtle. Take, for instance, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. The headings aren't bold and seem to be in a type that's only slightly larger than the prose:

[image: example]

I find the page harder to read. Can we adjust this?

Comment: Maybe provide an example of how you'd like it look? The whole post could be redone using [format markup](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and if you put it in your question or as an answer to your question that would be best.

Comment: I agree that it is hard to find a section with the current formatting. [This](http://imgur.com/qyxhCeQ) would be better imo.

Comment: @BrandonB The text used to be easier to read. I'm hoping a passing employee might comment on some recent changes to the styles. I think reproducing the page with my preferred formatting is probably a waste of time. If the titles were simply emboldened, that would probably do it.

Comment: I dont see anything wrong with it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have pushed a fix for this. The heading text in help center should be bigger and bolder now. The change will be live after our next production build.

Answer (score 7):

Using Chrome, I inspected the H3 heading "*Write a title that summarizes the specific problem*". Changing the weight of this to bold seemed to improve things:

[image: font weight change]

The resulting page:

[image: improved page]

Comment: While I agree that titles do not differentiate enough from normal text I strongly disagree with bold. If title is bigger then it _should_ be thinner to keep page balance. In short: I agree to change it but I'd make it bigger (with an extra 1em space before).